# Searching csv for value, code works in ipython but not when used in program

Tags: python, csv

I am beginner, just to preface.

I have a csv file like below:

**Hostname,ip,Model,Version,Group,Folder,Primary Switch,Switch Role**

switch-id-1,10.10.10.10,2848,WB.16.08.0001,HP Switches,Top > TYC,"  -",Commander

This code when run in ipython correctly finds the row with the ip and model '2848'.  When I run this in my program called as a function it always starts at the beginning of file and iterates through every row.  How do I just have it grab the row that contains the ip and model (10.10.10.10 and 2848).  I have tried using DictReader and a list but have not been able to get it.

```
with io.open('switches_all.csv') as f:
         reader = csv.reader(f)
         for k,v in enumerate(reader):
             if '10.10.10.10' in v and '2848' in v:
                 print(v)
```

Comment: `enumerate` does not do what you think based on this code, furthermore each line in the `reader` object is a `list`

Comment: Yes, the `enumerate` is not needed, but the code works for me as is. @dmw_code, this is a loop that iterates over each row, no matter where you execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV files are not indexed, so you certainly have to iterate through every row before you can find a row with the IP-address and model name you're looking for.

That said, if this function is to be called repeatedly for the duration of the script's execution, it is worth building such indices by mapping IP-addresses and model names to their respective file positions as a dict first, so that the function can retrieve the requested row in constant time:

```
mapping = {}
with open('switches_all.csv') as f:
    position = 0
    for _, ip, model, *_ in csv.reader(f)
        mapping[ip, model] = position
        position = f.tell()

def get_row(ip, model):
    with open('switches_all.csv') as f:
        try:
            f.seek(mapping[ip, model])
        except KeyError:
            raise RuntimeError('No row found with the given IP and model.')
        return next(csv.reader(f))

print(get_row('10.10.10.10', '2848'))
```

Comment: this is an excellent answer and shows OP several improvements

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I knew my approach was not quite right, I understand most of your code but can figure it out and it is going to further my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the number of the line in which you found it, the `k` value:

```py
with open('switches_all.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    line = reader[k]
```